# How to convert VB code to Java

Tags: java, vb.net

I'm trying to convert these VB functions to Java. this is what I have done so far. I'm having problem with getting the `nRandom` it always returns the value of `nLow` my suspect for this is the `R` as I've print `R` it always gives the answer `0.0`

Question: what is wrong with my Java code?

**VB CODE**

```
Function GetRandom(ByVal nLow As String, ByVal nHigh As String) As String

            Static boolStarted As Boolean
            Dim nRandom As String
            If Not boolStarted Then
                Randomize(Second(Now) / 100)
                Rnd()
            End If
            nRandom = Int((nHigh - nLow + 1) * Rnd() + nLow)
            GetRandom = nRandom
        End Function
```

**JAVA CODE**

```
private String GetRandom(String nLow, String nHigh)
    {
        boolean boolStarted=false;
        String nRandom;
        Date date=new Date();
        double R=0;
        if(boolStarted==false)
        {
            Random rnd=new Random();
            //R=rnd.nextInt(Math.round(date.getSeconds()/100));
            //R=rnd.nextDouble();
            R=Math.round(Integer.valueOf(date.getSeconds())/100);
        }

        System.out.println("Random: "+R);
        System.out.println("SEC: "+date.getSeconds());
        nRandom=String.valueOf((Integer.valueOf(nHigh)-Integer.valueOf(nLow)+1)*R+Integer.valueOf(nLow));
        return nRandom;
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug and see the value of R at each step if you suspect it's causing issues?

Comment: I tried `R=15/100;` and it still returns 0.0

Comment: `R = 15/100` should give you 0 if both are integers. You need to cast as `double` to get the value 0.15. Also, is there a particular reason you need to pass numeric arguments as strings?

Comment: Just an FYI for future reference, it's Java not JAVA, and it's common convention to use camelCase (getRandom) not PascalCase for Java method names; although, class names are still PascalCase. It's slightly useful to quickly identify Java from C# code out of context.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `Random` only once. From then on, calling `nextInt` or `nextDouble` will return random numbers. You also need to use doubles instead of ints so that calculated values are not rounded to integers.

```
public class RandomGenerator
{
    private Random _r = new Random();

    private String GetRandom(String nLow, String nHigh)
    {
        double low = Double.Parse(nLow);
        double high = Double.Parse(nHigh);

        double R = _r.nextDouble();
        string nRandom = ((high - low + 1) * R + low).ToString();
        return nRandom;
    }
}
```

Comment: While you are at it, change the parameters to double so that the conversion is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;

class GetRandom {

    String GetRandom(String nLow, String nHigh) {
        Random ran = new Random();
        double low = Double.parseDouble(nLow);
        double high = Double.parseDouble(nHigh);
        return ("" + ((high - low) * ran.nextDouble() + low));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GetRandom s = new GetRandom();
        String nLow = "2.5805"; // Lower value you want
        String nHigh = "80.5454"; // Higher value you want
        System.out.println(s.GetRandom(nLow, nHigh));
    }

}
```